# How do I populate and sort users by most recently logged in using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to Mongoose. I'm trying to sort by last user logged in.

How do I sort by date? i.e. `lastLogin: Date`

```
Project.populate(projects, {path: 'users'}, function(err, projects){
```

Comment: Can you post your model?

Comment: 'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', {
    password: String,
    username: String,
    isAdmin: Boolean,
    lastLogin: Date
});

Answer (score 0):

You could sort by last user logged in (considering `lastLogin` is the field) using/tweaking the following query:

Mongoose 4.x

`Project.populate({path: 'users', options: { sort: [['lastLogin', 'desc']] }}, function(err,projects){});`

or

`Project.populate({path: 'users', options: { sort: {'lastLogin': -1 }}}, function(err,projects){});`

I hope this will help you. But with the details you have provided in question this is max I can think of. If you need more details please consider updating you question

---

Mongoose 2.x & 3.x

`Project.populate('users', null, { sort: { 'created_at': -1 } })`

**Note:** in sort query 1 is equivalent to asc & -1 to desc

Comment: I have it set up so every time a user logs in, it creates a date and saves that date to the db. Now I'm trying to sort and display the last 5 users based on the time they logged in. So if user1 signed in at 4pm and user2 signed in at 5pm, it would display like this,

user2 signed in at 5pm
user1 signed in at 4pm

Comment: @ajax: Then the sort issue which is your initial question, for that you should have got the solution right ?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose has support for date sorting:

```
const loginHistory =
  User
    .find({ logged: true }) // if u want just logged users
    .sort({ lastLogin: 'desc' })
    .populate('whathever')
    .exec();

loginHistory.then(docs => {
  // sorted docs availables
});
```